# How can we get the iPhone's IMEI?

Tags: ios, iphone, imei

In my app, I need the iPhone's IMEI to distinguish between different devices，How do I get the iPhone's IMEI？

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that; if you need to distinguish between devices, `identifierForVender` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Type *#06# in your dialpad and you will get the 15-16 digit IMEI

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the IMEI/MEID number on virtually any phone by dialing in the universal code. Dial *#06#. You typically will not need to press the Call or Send button, as the IMEI/MEID number will appear as soon as you finish dialing the code.